# Big O, Big Omega, Big Theta functions

Tags: algorithm, big-o

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeNg2.jpg)

I am taking a data structures class, i am kind of confused on how to go with this type of problem. Any leads will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now it looks like you are just asking us to do your homework for you. What have you tried so far? What ideas do you have? Do you have an intuition for what's going on?

Comment: i don't , hence i asked for any leads. except for definition of Big-o i am kind of lost what to do.

Comment: @KaranSingla -- is my answer any guidance at all?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain one of these and see if you can make an attempt at the rest.

```
f(n) is O( g(n) )   "function f of n" is ("big O") **Order** g(n)

if for some n (maybe not f(0) or f(1)  or... but eventually for some n)
and for some **constant** (1, 2, 50, 80 million, something)

f(n) <= c * g(n)

So if we say some function f is "O(log n)" than means that starting at
some  n  that we pass into f(), and some number  c   then

    f(n) <= c * log(n)
```

Lets take a really simple example:

```
function f ( n ) {

     answer = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {        // loops n times
         answer += n+3;                // 2 ops: add, add
         answer /= (7*n);              // 2 ops: mult, div
         answer ^= 2;                  // 1 op:  xor
     }                                 // 2 + 2 + 1 = 5
     return answer;
}
```

So, we might say 'c' is 5, and g(n) is n (we clearly loop n times).

```
f (n)   <=   5 * g(n)
f (n)   <=   5 * n

f () is O(n)
```

basically what this is saying is the constant factors don't matter at all when n gets big enough. It makes almost no difference if f(n) is (5n) or (7n) or (27n) when we might compare it to other functions which could be (87log(n))   or (0.01n²).

```
     \ n   10     1000      100000
 f(n) \-----------------------------
    7n |   70     7000      700000       O(n) grows linearly with prob size
87logn | ~200     ~600       ~1000       O(log n) grows slowly [good!]
 .01n² |   10    10000   100000000       O(n²) grows fast [bad!]
```